# How to handle test case fails in Katalon Studio

Tags: katalon-studio

In my test case I decide whether I want to toggle my radio button. I check if my radio button does not have the `checked` attribute as follows:

```
TestObject srcCurrOpModeRadioBtn = guiUtils.createControl('config-src-op-mode-currentradio')
        if(WebUI.verifyElementNotHasAttribute(srcCurrOpModeRadioBtn, 'checked', 5)){
            TestObject srcCurrOpModeToggle = guiUtils.createControl('config-src-op-mode-current')
            WebUI.click(srcCurrOpModeToggle)
            WebUI.delay(1)
        }
```

This works fine when my object does not have the `checked` attribute, but when my object is already `checked` (in the state that I want it to be), my test case fails. How do I make it so that instead of failing, it carries out the remaining test?

In simpler words, I have a toggle that toggles between 2 modes, lets call them mode1 and mode2. This specific test tests mode1's preferences, so before testing mode1's preferences, I have to toggle to mode1. My logic works when the toggle is at mode2 at the start of the test but it fails when I am already on mode1. I know that it fails because when mode1 is selected, its radio button already has a `checked` attribute and so the `if` statement fails but I don't want my test case to fail because of this, I want to test mode1's preferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another parameter to `WebUI.verifyElementNotHasAttribute()` - [flow control](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/webui-verify-element-not-has-attribute.html#description).

You need to set `FailureHandling.OPTIONAL` so the test continues execution even if the function returns false. Then you can write the "else" part with corresponding logic.

Comment: NICE! Thank you very much, I had no idea it would be so simple :D